# AVRDude on Raspberry Pi programming ATTiny1634

Tags: raspberry-pi, avr, avrdude

I am using AVRDude 6.3 on a Raspberry Pi Zero to program an ATTiny1634. The microcontroller is soldered to a breakout board I made myself. It simply exposes the pins of the chip to pin headers which is sitting on a breadboard. I have connected the pins of the Pi to the SPI programming pins on the microcontroller using a tutorial I found on Adafruit and the datasheet of the ATTiny. Both the Pi and uC are powered from the same power supply, and 10k pullup resistors are on each of RESET, MOSI, and MISO (going to the uC). The microcontroller was purchased from Digikey.

The issue I am running into, is that AVRDude appears to program the chip, however when it tries to verify what was written, it fails on byte 0x0002 everytime. AVRDude appears to recognize the chip signature, and appears to correctly read the default values from the fuse bits. I have tried adding delays from 2 to 100 using the -i switch on AVRDude (to no avail) and everything is up to date using apt-get.

This is driving me nuts and I really have no idea where to go from here. I can post pictures of my setup as well as flash dumps later in the day if requested.

**In Summation:**
Should I just buy an AVRDragon?

**UPDATE:** I bought an AVRDragon, and it works perfectly. Thats what I get for trying to be cheap